# What is the error in the following program?

Tags: plsql, oracle10g, syntax-error

here is the PL/SQL program which i am writing to convert the string into ascii values but m getting the following error :

```
ORA-06550: line 12, column 5:
PLS-00113: END identifier 'FUNCTION' must match 'ENCODE12' at line 3, column 10
ORA-06550: line 12, column 13:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following: begin function package pragma procedure form
```

1. declare
2. buff number(3):=0;
3. function Encode12(string varchar2)

I am new PL/SQL programming. Thank in advance.

```
declare
buff number(3):=0;
function Encode12(string varchar2)
return varchar2 is 
encodedString varchar2(50):='';
Begin
for i in 1 .. length(string) loop 
buff:=ascii(substr(string,i,1));
concat(encodedString,buff);
end loop;
return encodedString;
end function;
```

Comment: Are you trying to create a function?  Or are you trying to create an anonymous PL/SQL block that declares a local function?

Comment: its a function.. user defined function which computes the value..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
create or replace function Encode12(string varchar2 )
return varchar2 is 
  encodedString varchar2(50):='';
  buff number(3):=0;
Begin
  for i in 1 .. length(string) loop 
     buff:=ascii(substr(string,i,1));
     -- concat(encodedString,buff);
     encodedString := encodedString || buff;
  end loop;
  return encodedString;
end;
/
```

There is no `concat` procedure in Oracle, an assignment and a concatenation operators must be used instead:

```
encodedString := encodedString || buff;
```

Please take a look at this demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/21309/1

Comment: Oracle does have a [`concat` function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions026.htm). `concat` doesn't cause the compilation failure reported by OP. But as you noticed his use of `concat` was effectively a no-op.